# What are the possible reasons if Kalman filter can not calculate a stabilizing Kalman gain?

Tags: matlab, estimation, kalman-filter, stochastic-process, state-space

I have a question about Kalman filter. I am using Kalman filter for a state space model as following:

```
X(k+1) = A(k)x(k)+B(k)u(k)+w(k), w(k) ∼ N(0,Q)
Y(k) = C(K)x(k)+D(k)u(k)+v(k), v(k) ∼ N(0,R)
```

Which the state space matrixes `(A(k),B(k),C(k),D(k))` are updated in each sampling time but Q and R matrixes are considered to be constant. The equations which calculate the Kalman gain (K(k)) and covariance P matrix (P(k)) are as following:

```
K(k) = (P(k)*C(k)' )/(R + C(k)*P(k)*C(k)');
Pxx(k) = (eye(n)-K(k)*C(k))*P(k)*(eye(n)-K(k)*C (k))'+K(k)*R*K(k)';%Joseph form
P(k) = A(k)*Pxx(k)*A(k)' + Q;
```

The problem that I face is related to stability of `(A(k)-K(k)*C(k))`. In some sampling times, the calculated Kalman gain can not stabilize the `(A(k)-K(k)*C(k))` matrix and the eigenvalues of `(A(k)-K(k)*C(k))` are outside of unit circle.

Could you please help me to figure out the reason for this problem? I am expecting that the Kalman filter gives me the gain which make the `(A(k)-K(k)*C(k))` matrix stable with eigenvalues inside the unit circle.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen when the system is *unobservable*. Check the rank of the *observability matrix*

```
O = [C(k)
     C(k)A(k)
     C(k)A(k)^2
     ...
     C(k)A(k)^(n-1)]
```

where `n` is the dimension of the state space (i.e., `A(k)` is `n X n` matrix). If the row rank of `O` is less than `n`, then you have the problem.

In matlab, `O = obsv(A,C)` will compute the observability matrix and `rank(O)` will give its rank.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This could also happen if the system is uncontrollable. Observability and controllability are the two criteria for an asymptotically stable Kalman gain.